# vb.net - Timer stops working when stopped and started

Tags: vb.net, timer, backgroundworker

I have an app that runs several timers.

The first is a heartbeat timer, HB_Timer, which fires off a backgroundworker at the set interval which runs a sql command to register a 'heartbeart'. 
The second is a reinit timer, Reinit_Timer, which again fires off a backgroundworker to query global settings from the database and, if the value for heartbeat interval has changed, stops HB_Timer, changes HB_Timer.Interval accordingly and then restarts HB_Timer.

I've amended the code below slightly to put it in its most simplistic format. 
The heartbeat interval in the DB is saved in seconds, so i multiply by 1000 to get ms before applying the interval...

```
 Public Function Endpoint_ReInit()
    Try
        HB_Timer.Stop()
        hb_interval = ReadSQLValue(<the data i need to read...>)
        If hb_interval > 0 Then HB_Timer.Interval = (hb_interval * 1000)
        HB_Timer.Start()
```

For some reason, once the timer is stopped, it wont start again programatically, and I can't see why. 
I've added console.writeline on the tick event of the timer and on firing the backgroundworker... both work before it is stopped and then restarted and then neither work (obviously, if the first doesnt then the second definitely wont).

I wondered if it was going to quickly so have tried sleeping for periods between stopping and starting, but that didn't work.

I even tried adding a temp button on my form to see if the timer could be manually restarted, and that doesn't work either.

I have error handling on all my functions etc and no exceptions are thrown.

I'm at a bit of a loss.... can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

At a guess the value returned from the SQL query is large, so it's not that the timer is stopped, it's just that it is taking a very long time before it ticks.

Or something crashes in your backgroundworker and thus your `timer.Start()` is never called (the call to `ReadSQLValue()` never returns). If `ReadSQLValue()` uses a BackgroundWorker, though I'm not really sure how you're managing the sync/async mixing, be aware that when a BackgroundWorker experiences an exception in `DoWork()` it doesn't may not end up in your code at the time it occurs. The BGW just fires the `RunWorkerCompleted` event with an EventArgs that has an exception in the `Error` property)

When I work with timers I tend to set them to some low interval, say 1 second, and if I want something to happen every minute for one process and two minutes for another I have a couple of ints that count down from 60/120 respectively and when they hit 0, I do the processes, and reset the ints back to 60/120. I don't stop/start/change the timer interval

Comment: I consoled out the values and triple checked them and everything seems fine.

Comment: I've actually managed to get it working by changing the timer type to system.timers.timer - but I'm still not sure why it wouldn't work normally.